# Modal bootstrap abrindo uma pagina de redirecionamento que não deveria dentro dele

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core

Dentro do controller das minhas partial View que sao abertas em modal eu faço uma validação se o token esta valido, caso ocorra tudo bem ela ira abrir e mostrar o conteúdo, e isto acontece normal, mas caso o token esteja expirado eu programei para que seja redirecionado para o método de deslogar, ai o usuario seria deslogado e teria que logar novamente, o que acontece e que o modal carrega a pagina de login e atualizando a pagina ele faz o processo que deveria ser feito.

segue o controller:

```
        [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Partial_Visualizar(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!SessaoExpirada)
            {
                var receita = await _receitaService.VisualizarReceitaId(id, Token);
                if (receita == null)
                {
                    return Json("Erro ao carregar receita!!");
                }
                var receitaMap = _mapper.Map<ReceitaModel>(receita);
                return View(receitaMap);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Deslogar", "LoginUsuario", new { msg = "Sessao expirada refaça o login" });
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return Json("Erro no servidor!");
        }
    }
```

segue o escript que abre os modais:

```
ShowInModal = (url, title, id) => {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    success: function (res) {
        $("#exampleModal .modal-body").html(res);
        $("#exampleModal .modal-title").html(title);
        $("#exampleModal").modal('show');
    }
});
```

};

segue o .csthml a parte que faz a chamada dos modais:

```
            @foreach (var modelo in Model)
        {
            <tbody>
                <tr class="table-light">
                    <th scope="row">@modelo.Id</th>
                    <td>@modelo.Titulo</td>
                    <td>@modelo.Data_Publicacao</td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Exemplo básico">
                            <a onclick="ShowInModal('@Url.Action("Partial_Visualizar","Perfil",new {id = modelo.Id},Context.Request.Scheme)','Visualizar Receita')"
                                class="visualizar btn btn-info btn-sm">Visualizar</a>
                            <a onclick="ShowInModal('@Url.Action("Partial_Editar","Perfil",new {id = modelo.Id},Context.Request.Scheme)','Editar Receita')"
                                class="editar btn btn-warning btn-sm">Alterar</a>
                            <a onclick="ShowInModal('@Url.Action("Partial_Delete","Perfil",new {id = modelo.Id},Context.Request.Scheme)',null)"
                                class="deletar btn btn-danger btn-sm">Deletar</a>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        }
```

imagem de erro que aparece no console do Chrome:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A minha duvida e por que este redirecionamento não e feito e por que a pagina de login e aberta dentro do modal, o que eu teria que mudar para que minha ideia funcionasse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você está fazendo a requisição a partir de uma função ajax na sua view, você terá o retorno ali também. Se você der um console.log(res), perceba que ali está dizendo que existe um redirecionamento.

Eu sugiro que altere o retorno, por exemplo um status code 401 de não autorizado.

ao invés de

```
    return RedirectToAction("Deslogar", "LoginUsuario", new { msg = "Sessao expirada refaça o login" });
```

use

```
  return Unauthorized(); //status code 401
```

faça algo assim na sua função

```
 success: function (res) {
  if(res.statuscode == 401) 
   { 
       window.location.href = '/LoginUsuario/Deslogar';
   }

    $("#exampleModal .modal-body").html(res);
    $("#exampleModal .modal-title").html(title);
    $("#exampleModal").modal('show');
}
```

Você pode manter seu controller da maneira que está também se quiser, mas de uma olhada no que está retornando, e faça o redirecionamento se existir...

Comment: Obrigado marcos pela resposta! já tinha ate resolvido isto mas de uma maneira feia criando um botão no controller mesmo e feito uma função para atualizar a pagina. Mas a sua resposta não funcionou exatamente, mas fazendo algumas pesquisas adicionei um error abaixo so success: ` error: function () {
                var msg = 'Sessao expirada refaça o login';
                window.location.href = `/LoginUsuario/Deslogar?msg=${msg}`;
            }` e mantive o unathorized que vc indicou e agora esta funcionando de boa vlw man!!